# Accessing strings.xml from ViewModel

Tags: android, android-context, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am using `Dagger 2 DataBindng` and the new Android Lifecycle components, which have `ViewModels`.

Inside my `ViewModel` how could I get access to my strings.xml? I was thinking at first, to inject a `Context` into the `viewModel`, however, this will just leak memory.

Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 7):

There is an [`AndroidViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel.html), which receives `Application` instance as parameter.

From docs:

> Application context aware **ViewModel**.
>
> Subclasses must have a constructor which accepts **Application** as the only parameter.

You can retrieve a string from `strings.xml` using that parameter.

---

> The repo in the link, however uses **ViewModel** and not AndroidViewModel. If I extend my ViewModel to use **AndroidViewModel** and include the **Application** - it's trying to inject **MyApplication** instead of **Application** if that makes sense.

I've checked out [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample). Here's how `UserViewModel` looks like:

```
    public class UserViewModel extends ViewModel {
        ...
        @Inject
        public UserViewModel(UserRepository userRepository, RepoRepository repoRepository) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

And here's what changes I've done:

```
    public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
        ...
        @Inject
        public UserViewModel(Application application, UserRepository userRepository, RepoRepository repoRepository) {
            super(application);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I still have an issue. Since I use Dagger, I use constructor injection in my Models. This means I cannot use AndroidViewModel. Any ideas?

Comment: See how `ViewModel`s are being injected in [GithubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components).

Comment: That's how I inject my ViewModels. The repo in the link, however uses ViewModel and not AndroidViewModel. If I extend my ViewModel to use AndroidViewModel and include the Application - its trying to inject MyApplication instead of Application if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you still unit test `ViewModel` with `JUnit`? If I just need to pass strings from `ViewModel` to view, isn't it more accurate if I pass String Resource Ids back from `Viewmodel` to View?

Comment: @mallaudin, you are correct, it's better to pass string ids instead of strings itself, one of the reasons of doing that is outlined in [this post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/locale-changes-and-the-androidviewmodel-antipattern-84eb677660d9).

Comment: Thanks @azizbekian for sharing post.