# Cannot Create Instance Of Class ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently working on a countdown app, and whenever I open it, it fails with a message saying `Cannot create instance of class com.nailuj29gaming.CountdownViewModel`

The stack trace is

```
    Process: com.nailuj29gaming.countdown.debug, PID: 17800
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nailuj29gaming.countdown.debug/com.nailuj29gaming.countdown.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.nailuj29gaming.countdown.CountdownViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2750)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.nailuj29gaming.countdown.CountdownViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.nailuj29gaming.countdown.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6757)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2703)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762) 
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.nailuj29gaming.countdown.CountdownViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.nailuj29gaming.countdown.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6757) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2703) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

I know there is a [very similar question, this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998051/cannot-create-an-instance-of-class-viewmodel), but that is target at Java, and my code is written in Kotlin. My `ViewModel` class's text is

```
package com.nailuj29gaming.countdown

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class CountdownViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repo: CountdownRepo
    val countdowns: LiveData<List<Countdown>>

    init {
        val countdownDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application).countdownDao()
        repo = CountdownRepo(countdownDao)
        countdowns = repo.countdowns

    }

    fun insert(countdown: Countdown) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.insert(countdown)
    }

    fun delete(countdown: Countdown) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repo.delete(countdown)
    }
}
```

I create the `ViewModel` in the first line of my `MainActivity.onCreate()` method. The code I used to create it is `viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CountdownViewModel::class.java)`

My build.gradle file (at least what matters in this question) is

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    def room_version = "2.2.3"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
    implementation 'net.steamcrafted:materialiconlib:1.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
}
```

I tried using a factory, but the ViewModelProviders class is deprecated
[image: deprecation]

When I used a delegate, the IDE did not give me an error, but the compiler said

```
Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option
```

My code is compiled into bytecode built with JVM target 1.8, so this error shouldn't show, right?

Comment: Please show where you get your ViewModel instance in the Activity.

Comment: You need a factory for the `CountdownViewModel` because its constructor needs arguments

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade to Fragment 1.2.0 or higher, which is what adds a support for the `ViewModelProvider` constructor as per the [Lifecycle 2.2.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0):

> You can pass a Fragment or FragmentActivity to the new ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner) constructor to achieve the same functionality when using [Fragment 1.2.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.2.0).

When using an older version of Fragments (i.e., the Fragment 1.1.0 that AppCompat 1.1.0 pulls in), you'll only get the `ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory` you see in your exception trace, rather than a ViewModel.Factory that supports `AndroidViewModel`.

Therefore you should add an explicit dependency on Fragment 1.3.5 (the current latest):

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.5'
```

Comment: Note that if you included `fragment-ktx` of even 1.1.0, you'd get the right behavior when using `val viewModel: CountdownViewModel by viewModels()` - you never needed to use `ViewModelProviders.of()` in Kotlin.

Comment: I edited my question with the compilation error produced when I tried your method.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the `kotlinOptions` section mentioned on the [Java8 Support documentation page](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support).

Comment: Our app includes both the old and the new androidx.fragment dependencies. How come, on some devices it works perfect, while others experience this crash?
Is that random? Or do users with certain conditions always get the crash?

Comment: @Entreco - apps can only have one version of a dependency in their apk - the latest version is always chosen by Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

This post helped me, as I was facing a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60670866/6030520

To address the error you were getting
(`Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option`), you can simply add:

```
android { 

    ...

    kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "1.8" }

}
```

... to your app/build.gradle file.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider this line from the stacktrace

> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
>   java.lang.Class has
>   no zero argument constructor

This means you should pass an argument in the constructor when you buildng your `viewmodel`

In the link you quoted there is a specific kotlin answer][1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51577426/4721831)

***EDIT:***
And also control that you have correctly insta intiated the factory as shown in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829280/how-to-use-a-viewmodelprovider-factory-when-extends-from-androidviewmodel) or this other [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46283981/android-viewmodel-additional-arguments)

Comment: What do you mean by pass an argument to the constructor? I thought when creating a ViewModel, the class must have a a single argument constructor with an `Application` argument.

Comment: please see my edit, you may need to check your `build.gradle` file and change annotation processor with `kapt` as in kotlin is recommended

Comment: I tried the kotlin answer to that question, and it didn't do anything

Comment: you mean you checked the gradle file and you do not use annotation processor?

Comment: Yes. I will add the build.gradle file to my question

Comment: I believe you:) what is important is how you instantiated from the activity the viewModel, did you use a factory as shown in my edit @Nailuij29 ?

Comment: No, I did not use a factory. I will try that

Comment: there is also a second example I linked even easier in my edit to use the factory. I agree that is confusing but save some boilerplate code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207861/discussion-between-nailuj29-and-trocchietto).